# Kotlin: unresolved reference to member variable?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

My class `NotesListAdapter` has a member variable `context` but when I try to call this member variable in the below function, I get an unresolved reference error. I'm new to Kotlin, so I'm confused about what is going on here.

```
class NotesListAdapter(context:Context,list:List<Notes>,listener:NotesClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NotesViewHolder {
        return NotesViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.notes_list,parent,false))
    }
}
```

Comment: According to Android Studio, the offending code is only the call of context, and if I create a second variable say `var contextx = context` and then call that in my return it seems to work, so i am confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass the variable in as `(context: Context` you have created a local variable that is only available during initialization, not a class member. For example, in this case `s` is not available to use in `printmys()` but it is available in `init` or in inline declarations:

```kotlin
class TestClass(s: String) {

    fun printmys() {
        println(s) // not valid
    }

    init {
        println(s) // valid
    }

    private val mys = s // also valid
}
```

To declare it as a private class member so you can use it in your functions, add a declaration like `private val` or `var` before it like this:

```kotlin
class NotesListAdapter(private val context: Context
```

Or, using the example above

```kotlin
class TestClass(private val s: String) {
    fun printmys() {
        println(s) // valid
    }
}
```